# ChromeDriver file upload example

Tags: java, google-chrome, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

ChromeDriver dev team says thet have fixed the issue here: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=1725&q=chrome%20file%20upload&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary

But I am not able to implement it. Can somebody show me an example or any workaround for testing file upload on Chrome using ChromeDriver?.

Comment: I do not know of any solution. I am looking for one. especially for Unix based machines.(Like Mac or Linux). AutoIT is only for windows.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
driver.findElement(By.id("upload")).sendKeys("/path/to/the/file");
```

Comment: It works fine in Chrome. We have tests that cover this in the Selenium tree.

Comment: Thanks Jarib for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I know people have done it through [AutoIT](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) when there was no support for Alert. Perhaps a workaround until the Alert is supported in ChromeDriver?